# Error while executing mysql commands inside docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When I execute the xdcomp_my_sql_client command it pings the ip but then when it tries to reach the mysql server it fails. If I do the exact same command once the container is running it works. It seems that the mysql server is not running at the moment the command is executed. But I have used the "depends_on" command, so what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

```
version: '2'

services:
  xdcomp_my_sql_server:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: diego
      MYSQL_USER: otro
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: otro
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: 172.28.0.101
    networks:
      SQLNetwork:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.0.102

  xdcomp_my_sql_client:
    build: .
    command: sh -c 'ping -c 5 172.28.0.102 && mysql -h 172.28.0.102 -u root -pdiego sys < /lafayette/forensic.sql && tail -f /etc/hostname'
    ports:
      - 83:80
    networks:
      SQLNetwork:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.0.101
    depends_on:
      - xdcomp_my_sql_server


networks:
  SQLNetwork:
    driver: "bridge"
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.28.0.0/24
          gateway: 172.28.0.201
```

## Client Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-client
RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN git clone https://github.com/linkedin/lafayette
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python-dnspython
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip
RUN pip install Flask
RUN pip install python-dateutil
RUN apt-get install -y python-mysqldb
RUN pip install requests
RUN pip install multiprocessing
RUN pip install multiprocess
RUN apt-get install -y vim
RUN apt-get -y install iputils-ping
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with docker includes 2 steps:

- building a image
- creating container based on image and running this container

The point is you `mysql client` can connect to server **only** on second step.

`Dockerfile` "executes" while you build image. In this time you don't have any containers, therefore you can`t connect to them. 
You need move command

`RUN cd lafayette && mysql –h 172.25.0.102 –u root –ppass sys < forensic.sql`

from `Dockerfile` to [entrypoint.sh](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint)

*Can you show me your Dockerfile? I will try to fix the issue*

Comment: Thank you I understand now why I was wrong in doing that. But I still have issues trying to do what I want. I want to upload a database from the client container to the server container once the docker-compose for those 2 containers is running.  I tried the following command in the docker-compose:     command: sh -c 'ping -c 5 172.28.0.102 && mysql -h 172.28.0.102 -u root -ppass sys < /lafayette/forensic.sql && tail -f /etc/hostname'. The ping works but I got: ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.28.0.102'. But If I run the same command inside the container it works.

Comment: Ite seems that the mysql server is not running at the time I execute the command.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the following: the mysql server was not running at the time the client command was executed. Even when the key "depends_on" was present (see:https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) For that reason the solution was to wait for the mysql server. This was done with the following command:

> command: sh -c 'until nc -z -v -w20 172.28.0.102 3306; do sleep 1;
>   echo "Waiting for mysqlserver to come up..."; done && ping -c 5 172.28.0.102 &&
>   mysql -h 172.28.0.102 -u root -pdiego sys < /lafayette/forensic.sql &&
>   tail -f /etc/hostname'

The wait for was made by the following line:

> until nc -z -v -w20 172.28.0.102 3306; do sleep 1;
>   echo "Waiting for mysqlserver to come up..."; done

nc= netcat command, it check the connection to a given ip and port